# What happens when a variable has the same name as the setter method?

Tags: ruby

I recently encountered this situation in Ruby that I don't seem to quite understand. Let's take a look at this code:

```rb
class Something
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def some_method
    name = name
    name
  end
end
```

So, if I instantiate Something like so:

`sth = Something.new('hello')`

I would expect `sth.some_method` to return `hello` but instead I get `nil`

Why is this?

The only thing I can think of is I'm essentially redefining what `name` means in the context of `#some_method` so when `name` is assigned to itself then it basically doesn't know what `name` is anymore, would that make sense?

Edit:

I could instead do `@name = name` or `self.name = name` and that would be fine, I was just curious about this particular scenario.

Comment: The @ sigil is used for instance variables; your example is using a local variable that hasn't been assigned a value.

Comment: As soon as you do `name =` something, Ruby creates a new variable `name` with the value `nil`, then it gets assigned the value on the right side, after the equals sign. Since at that point `name` is already a variable with the value `nil` it will just stays as `nil`.

Comment: @Viktor, right yeah that's what I thought. Because otherwise calling `name` (the method) directly without defining `name` (the variable) would indeed give me `hello`